# Crear una instancia de otro ArrayList

Tags: java, array, serialización

Tengo un ArrayList en una clase y quiero hacer referencia de ella en otra clase, he leído que puedo copiar un ArrayList de esta forma:

`ArrayList<Persona> profesor= new ArrayList<>(persona);`

Sin embargo, cada vez que ejecuto me da un **NullPointerException** como si el ArrayList hiciera referencia a un objeto válido.

Lo estoy utilizando en este metodo serializador.

```
        public void serializar() {

      ArrayList<Contacto> contacto= new ArrayList<>(arreglo);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("contactos.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        if(oos != null)
        {
            oos.writeObject(contacto);
            oos.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contacto guardado");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hubo un error en el proceso\n"
                + "Ha ocurrido el siguiente error: \n"+e);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por qué simplemente no usas un getter?

```
Class Contactos {

    private List<Contacto> contactos;

    ...

    public List<Contacto> getContactos() { return contactos; }
}
```

Si solo existirá esa lista en toda la aplicación, puedes hacer un [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) que contenga la lista y usarla cuando haga falta. O también, puedes hacerla estática.

Respecto al **NullPointerException** es porque la lista que le estás pasando es nula; no tiene referencia.